# How to build a string with charAts?

Tags: java, string, int, charat

My assignment is to build a MMDDCCYY date string in Java.  If I'm given a julian date (e.g. Jan. 31 would be 31, Dec. 31 would be 365) I'm supposed to translate it into MMDDCCYY format (01/31/2014, 12/31/2014).  However, I can't figure out how to "build" a string.  If I have the month, date, and year ints, how do I construct those into a string?

Please note the below code would not work, because then it'd only return "1/1/2014" instead of "01/01/2014"

```
int month, day = 1;
int year = 2014;
String MMDDCCYY = (month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
```

How do I go about doing this correctly?  I tried using charAts, but not quite sure how to go about it, granted that's even the right way to do it.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Well, if the day or month is less than 10, then prepend a 0 to it.

Comment: There is no automagic string padding, either use `String.format` or better use a real `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` or manual pad as suggest above

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.format("%02d/%02d/%d, month, day, year)` to get your whished format `01/01/2014`. Better it would be to use [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and the use the format function of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm).

Comment: Hi @Ben if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.